# Can I use a different version of gcc inside Xcode?

Tags: macports, xcode, gcc

I installed gcc4.7 from MacPorts and I would like to use it inside Xcode (4.5). Is there a way to achieve this setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The closet thing i found to using GCC4.7 installed by Macports on XCode is from by using the method used in this link.

http://www.implbits.com/About/Blog/tabid/78/post/building-with-gcc-4-6-on-osx/Default.aspx

Hope it helps. I installed GCC4.7.2 manually i am still trying to figure how to use it with XCode without installing Macports. I have Homebrew installed, i recently removed Macports for Homebrew since you cannot have both Macports or Homebrew installed on the same machine might remove Homebrew and return back to Macports.